# I will do a moullet without right-click in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans

i'am using the `NetBeans 8.1` for programming . 
my probleme is : if i will do a `moullet` in the editor ( with mouse of portable ) , the editor of `netbeans` show window of `right-click` . 
how deactivate the right-click in `NetBeans` ?

Comment: What is a “moullet”?

Comment: midel button in the mouse

Comment: Edit your Question with clarifications rather than post as comments. Also, spelling is 'middle'. Lastly, I'm not sure this issue is appropriate to Stack Overflow.